# Transferring sole ownership: unique_ptr vs move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

It seems like `std::unique_ptr` solves a problem that can also be solved with move-semantics, i.e. transferring ownership of a uniquely-owned resource. Here are some examples where they seem to perform the same job:

```
class SomeResource { /* resourcey stuff */ };

void ProcessResourcePtr(std::unique_ptr<SomeResource> r) { /* do stuff */ }
void ProcessResourceRvalRef(SomeResource&& r) { /* do stuff */ }

class OwnerOfResourcePtr {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeResource> r_;
public:
    OwnerOfResourcePtr(std::unique_ptr<SomeResource> r) : r_(std::move(r)) { }
};

class OwnerOfResourceRvalRef {
private:
    SomeResource r_;
public:
    OwnerOfResourceRvalRef(SomeResource&& r) : r_(std::move(r)) { }
};


int main()
{
    // transfer ownership to function via unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<SomeResource> r1(new SomeResource());
    ProcessResourcePtr(std::move(r1));

    // transfer ownership to function via rvalue ref
    SomeResource r2;
    ProcessResourceRvalRef(std::move(r2));

    // transfer ownership to instance via unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<SomeResource> r3(new SomeResource());
    OwnerOfResourcePtr(std::move(r3));

    // transfer ownership to instance via rvalue ref
    SomeResource r4;
    OwnerOfResourceRvalRef(std::move(r4));

    return 0;
}
```

To my eye, these both solve almost exactly the same problem in slightly different ways. I'm not 100% clear on the advantages of one way versus the other. I know that pointer moves are probably faster than move constructors/assignments, although both are usually assumed to be quite efficient. I'm also aware that move semantics allow you to keep your data on the stack (see r2, r4) instead of requiring a heap allocation/deallocation with new/malloc/etc (see r1, r3), which I think is a good thing (is it?).

In general when should one prefer a `unique_ptr` over move semantics, or vice-versa? Are there any use cases that can only be solved by one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a class (perhaps written by someone else) which does not have a move constructor, perhaps not even a copy constructor, then you may have to use `unique_ptr`.

If an instance is optional, i.e. may not be present, you should use `unique_ptr`.

If you can only initialize an object after your constructor is called, and the object is not default-constructible,  you must delay construction, and can use `unique_ptr` for this.

Even if a class has a move constructor, that might be more expensive than moving a single pointer.  For example, if the class contains dozens of POD instances, or an array.

Comment: If the instance is optional you should use `std::experimental::optional` or `boost::optional`. It doesn't make sense to use `std::unique_ptr` for this. Also, I don't think the OP's question even makes sense. `std::unique_ptr` shows an ownership policy package that you can reuse. It feels like it boils down to 'When should I use `std::unique_ptr` instead of my own ownership policy?'.

Comment: @Rapptz: `std::unique_ptr` is part of standard C++, which for some people is a distinct advantage over `experimental` or `boost`.  I agree that the OP seems to look for an excuse to avoid `std::unique_ptr` when it is in fact quite useful.

Comment: `std::experimental::optional` is technically also part of the standard. Just like things in TR1 were part of the standard at the time. Both clang and gcc support `std::experimental::optional`.

Comment: You're both right; I accidentally created my own ownership policy but felt like something was off because I wasn't using `unique_ptr` (pretty new to c++, if it's not obvious). I knew there had to be some advantage to `unique_ptr` or they wouldn't have bothered to make it, but since my policy hadn't caused any problems yet I wasn't seeing them. @John Zwinck did an excellent job of describing where my policy would run into pain points in the future. @Rapptz, I'll read up on the various `optional` packages. Seems good to know about whether or not you use them. Thanks all.

Comment: @Rapptz:  `std::experimental` is not part of any standard.  `TR1` was never part of any standard.  They are simply experiments.  You can view them as the standards committee saying:  We are interested in this API and we are seeking more field experience and feedback on them.  Indeed, this is why I lobbied hard for the namespace "experimental" as opposed to the easily misunderstood "tr1".